# C# Winform Binary Icon

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, binary, icons

I want to change the icon my binary has for my applications.  The people I work with aren't technologically savvy and quite literally changed AppName.exe to CLICK ME.exe because they didn't know which icon to click...

Anyway, I figure an easy solution to this is to just make all of my applications for them have the same, bright icon so they will never be so confused again.  I have no idea how to do this, and haven't found much help on google.

I hope I don't get dinged too hard on my rep, because I'm not even sure this is a programming question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binary icon can be set from project properties, section "Application".

Answer (score 3):

Open the properties for the application's project and go to the "Application" tab.  In the "Icon and manifest" section, you can select an ico file to be the application icon.  That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is in a sea of icons anyway, everything starts to look the same.  I actually propose that you not bother with this, and create shortcuts on the desktop for them instead.  They can even have a "Steve H's apps" folder on the desktop with all shortcuts there.  When you deploy, have NSIS or IS or whatever installer you use create the shortcuts as well.

Comment: Hey whatdoya know? Three answers on how to do it and one better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the project in Solution Explorer, select Properties and, in the displayed window, set the Icon to be used for your project output.